# PWA: how to refresh content every time the app is opened

Tags: refresh, progressive-web-apps

I created a PWA app which sends API call to my domotic server and prints the response on the home page (e.g. outside temperature and vacuum robot status).

While all the data get refreshed at very first app opening, if I minimize the app whithout completely shutting it off I have no data refreshing at all.

**I was wondering how to force a refresh every time the app gets re-opened without having to do it manually** (no pull-down to refresh, no refresh-button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that works.

You can place this code wherever you have access to the window object:

```
    window.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
      console.log("Visibility changed");
      if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
        console.log("APP resumed");
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
```

Consider this may affect user experience or data loss with a forced reload every time the user swipes between apps.

Comment: As a side note, I agree with the user experience (UX). I myself have tried the 'refresh every time' scenario, but user experience was terrible. 

The bad UX comes from the fact that the new files take a few seconds to download. Once it downloads, the app refreshes itself. This is usually in the middle of, or after the user logged. Now the app refresh and logs the user out.

Since a PWA behaves like an app, the UX is better if you allow the user themselves to make the choice to 'update' the application.

Answer (score 2):

Found myself the solution adding the following code in service worker:

```
self.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
        console.log('APP resumed');
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reload, so users get the lastest version of your website (in the PWA), I recommend push notifications and whenever they receive it, boom, `window.reload()`.
Another and easier approach may be adding a weekly timeout to `window.reload()`.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate the details of your solution proposals, otherwise your contrbution risk being perceived as a mere comment and flagged and deleted for not being an answer according to [answer]. Please consider [edit] accordingly.